# I want to prevent the time range from entering to array that falls in between already entered time

Tags: jquery

```
Array(2)
0: {StrngStartDate: ""09/19/2020 06:00:00"", StrngEndDate: ""09/19/2020 07:00:00"", GoalId: 16352, CreatedBy: NaN, ReasonForAdding: "tre", …}
1: {StrngStartDate: ""09/19/2020 06:00:00"", StrngEndDate: ""09/19/2020 06:30:00"", GoalId: 16352, CreatedBy: NaN, ReasonForAdding: "rrre", …}
```

I have array of 2 as shown above. In above array one of the fields has start time and end time of 6:00am -7:00am. I want that if a user tries to add one more object in the same array as the second entry has start time and end time of 6:00am-6:30 am then it will not allow that array to be added as that time entry is already there and 6:00am-6:30am falls between that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the current entries and compare the timestamps as [javascript Date() objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Subtracting `Date()` objects returns the difference in miliseconds, so something like:

```
 let new_entry = {
   StrngStartDate: '09/19/2020 06:00:00', 
   StrngEndDate: '09/19/2020 06:30:00'
 };
 
 $.each(current_entries, function(index, entry) {
   if ((new Date(entry.StringStartDate)) - (new Date(new_entry.StringStartDate)) < 0) {
     //new entry start is after existing entry
   } else if ((new Date(entry.StringEndDate)) - (new Date(new_entry.StringEndDate)) > 0) {
     //new entry end time is before existing end time
   } else {
     current_entries.push(new_entry);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Yes its working. Thanks for the help. You saved my time.@PoorlyWrittenCode